No border connections in OSM data
I used OSMNX to download States in Germany as well as surrounding States from other countries to do mobility-analyses. These States get merged back together in my GDB. However at borders (no matter if country or state borders) most of the connecting streets are missing, so accessibility isochrones for example do not show the actual area which is accessible. Of course it is possible to reconnect the features in question by hand, but that would be quit the (with every update repeating) effort.
Does anyone have an idea what might have caused this issue or better yet how to resolve it?
EDIT: Services like traveltime.com seem to have the same problem.

